# Оптимизация сортировки списка

Tags: c#, asp.net, сортировка

Существует глобальный список новостей

```
 List<NewsItem> allNews = new List<NewsItem>();
```

Мне нужно взять все эти новости, отсортировать по дате, не трогая глобальный список, и вывести какой-то диапазон, что я и делаю.

```
 var sortedNews = sortedByDate ? allNews.OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate).ToList() :
     allNews.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).ToList();

 var articleRange = sortedNews.GetRange(firstIndex, itemsCount);
```

операция копирования+сортировка занимает слишком много памяти. Можно ли как-то уменьшить размер используемых ресурсов?

Comment: откуда берутся `firstIndex` и `itemsCount`?

Comment: @Igor firstIndex - это число, с которого начинается выборка элементов , а itemsCount - количество элементов для выборки.

Comment: разве я это спрашивал? Как определяются значения этих переменных?

Comment: @Igor  `static public HomePageModel GetHomePage(int page, bool sortedByDate)
        {
            int newsItemsQuantity = 15;

            var newsItemList = Storage.GetItems(page * newsItemsQuantity, newsItemsQuantity, sortedByDate);`

Answer (score 2):

Ресурсы выделяются в момент вызова `ToList`, соответственно нужно убрать лишние вызовы.

Код можно сделать красивее

```
var articleRange = allNews
    .OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate, !sortedByDate)
    .Skip(firstIndex-1)
    .Take(itemsCount)
    .ToList();
```

Для этого нужно добавить свой метод расширения

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
        bool isDesc = false
    )
    {
        return isDesc ? source.OrderByDescending(keySelector) : source.OrderBy(keySelector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `Skip` и `Take`:

```
 var sortedNews = (sortedByDate ? allNews.OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate) :
     allNews.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate))
     .Skip(firstIndex-1).Take(itemsCount).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Так ты берешь и создаешь еще одну копию своих данных. Следовательно потребляешь в два раза больше памяти. Обойдись без .ToList(), так у тебя будет только IEnumerable, далее работай с ним. Пройдись циклом по нему и добавляй нужные записи в articleRange.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx

Либо пробуй использовать LINQ
https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/15.3.php